# cURL - require cookies and session?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to log in a website using php via cURL. But the website I am trying to log in requires cookies and session I am new to php what is the best way to set up cookies and session so that I can log in I have tried $_SESSION and setcookies they don't seem to work.. here is the code I have written any help on this topic would be helpful thanks

```
  <?php
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/logint");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);


$data = array(
'username' => 'username',
'passwd' => 'pass',

);




curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);

 echo($output);

 curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To login to a webpage using curl and get the cookie you do something like this:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -d "username=myUser&password=FooBar" http://xyz.com/login
```

and to use those cookie in later requests you do:

```
curl -b cookies.txt  http://whatever.com/getPage
```

P.S: Not sure abt PHP syntax